# Angular array works in console but not in dom

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

thank You for reading. I'm a Angular beginner and have an first problem I can't solve. I read many, many posts without success, sorry.

My seach form is working fine if I get the search phrase in one component and process it in another component. The *ngFor loop gives back the right result-array in dom and console: searchCustomer(phrase).

The exactly same search function works not, if I include a header component with another search form - although I get the right results via console(!). I included the header via app-header in component.html.

Why contains the array "results" the right items but the dom isn't showing it? This is my code:

search.component.html:

```
<form #f = "ngForm" action="verification" method="get">  
 <input [(ngModel)] = "phrase" type="text" name="phrase">
 <button type="button" (click)="searchCustomer()">Search</button>
</form>
```

search.component.ts:

```
searchCustomer() {    
 this.dataService.setPhrase(this.phrase); //  store phrase     
 this.router.navigate(['/results']); // navigate
}
```

result.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let vs of results">
 ... 
</div>
```

result.component.ts:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// add ApiService
import { ApiService } from '../~services/api.service'; // ApiService
// add customers Model
import { Customer } from '../~interfaces/customers';
// DataService
import { DataService } from "../~services/data.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
})

export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

   // add array:
   results: Customer[];

   // add variable
  phrase: string;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService, 
    private dataService: DataService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  searchCustomer(phrase) {
    // search 
    this.apiService.searchCustomer(phrase).subscribe((result:Customer[]) => {
      this.results = result;
      console.log(this.results);

      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }        
    )
  }

}
```

header.component.html:

```
<form #f = "ngForm">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "phrase" type="text" value="{{phrase}}">
  <button type="button" (click)="searchCustomer()">Search</button>
</form>
```

header.component.html:

```
searchCustomer(){ 
 this.dataService.setPhrase(this.phrase);   
 this.resultComponent.searchCustomer(this.phrase);
}
```

If I start the search from Header, I can see the correct array "results" in Console, but not in dom. There is no refreshing.

Thank you for eye-opening,
Matthias

Comment: can you share the result.component.ts code? do you use   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post above and completed the result.component.ts. I use ChangeDetectorRef, but I don't got a different result. Maybe it is not right implemented? Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution in result.component.ts

```
responsePage$: Observable<ResponsePage>;
     
ngOnInit() {
          this.apiService.searchCustomer(phrase).subscribe((result:Customer[]) => {
              this.results = result;
              this.searchCustomer(phrase);
        });}


searchCustomer(phrase) {
    this.responsePage$=this.apiService.customers(phrase);
}
```